# How can I fix my regex so parameter 3 stays in capture group 3?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have the following regex expression:

```
^(\d*)(?:\.)(\d*)(?:|(?:\.)(\d*))(?:|(?:\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*))?$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Nwgkdz/1).
I want to use it to parse a version number into groups, for example (where g1 is the group number 1 and so on):

```
1.2              =>  g1(1),g2(2)    
1.2.3            =>  g1(1),g2(2),g3(3)    
1.2.3.4_or_text  =>  g1(1),g2(2),g3(3),g4(4_or_text)
```

This almost works, except if the third group is optional, and skips to the fourth group if the version has 3 parts.
So what actually happens is this:

```
1.2              =>  g1(1),g2(2)    
1.2.3            =>  g1(1),g2(2),g3(),g4(3)           <-- I want to fix this
1.2.3.4_or_text  =>  g1(1),g2(2),g3(3),g4(4_or_text)
```

I can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

The way it is working now also means that the following is valid: 
`1.2.3_or_text` since that is parsed as `g1(1),g2(2),g3(),g4(3_or_text)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split the string instead of regex?

Comment: Yes, but at this point I want to know. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having extra `alternation(|)` expression in your regex

```
^(\d*)(?:\.)(\d*)(?:|(?:\.)(\d*))(?:|(?:\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*))?$
                    ^               ^
                   this            this
```

It tells to match **nothing** which always passes. As a result your second part of alternation never matches.

**Further explanation**: Alternation syntax is like

```
(?:a|b|c)
```

In your case `a` is nothing, that's why its always true and matches

**Correct Solution**: You are also missing optional group and assuming there should be at least one digit or alphabet, [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/Nwgkdz/6) should be correct regex

```
^(\d+)(?:\.)(\d+)(?:(?:\.)(\d+))?(?:(?:\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?$
```

[**Bit of clean Solution**](https://regex101.com/r/Nwgkdz/7)

```
^(\d+)[.](\d+)(?:[.](\d+)(?:[.]([\w-]+))?)?$
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
 (\d+)[.] #Match digit and dot
 (\d+) #Match next group

 (?: #Non-capturing group
   [.](\d+) #Match dot and digit
   (?:[.]([\w-]+))? #Match dot and digit. This is optional
 )? #Third and Fourth match can be optional

$ #End of string
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with 2 optional non-capturing groups:

```
^(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.([\w-]+))?)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nwgkdz/3)

**Details:**

- ^`: Start
- `(\d+)`: Match and capture 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `\.`: Match a literal `.`
- `(\d+)`: Match and capture 1+ digits in capture group #2
- `(?:` Start non-capture group #1

  - `\.`: Match a literal `.`
  - `(\d+)`: Match and capture 1+ digits in capture group #3
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `\.`: Match a literal `.`
    - `([\w-]+)`: Match and capture 1+ word or hyphen chaaracters in capture group #4
  - `)?`: End non-capture group #2 (optional)
- `)?`: End non-capture group #1  (optional)
- `$`: End